# Unable to open the Excel workbook on SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, excel-services

I am unable to open the Excel workbooks from our production site in SharePoint 2010. The same Excel file was uploaded to UAT and it is working fine. Please find the fig below for the exact error am facing.

[image]

Comment: do  you have the excel service conifgured?

Comment: Yes Waqas its being configured

Comment: and it is associated with the web application? Go to Central admin > > Application Manager >Manage Web Applications > Click on the Web aplication then from Ribbon click on the Service Connections.....Now make Sure Excel Service is connected.

Comment: Hi Waqas I have checked my Web Application settings which am facing issue with and Excel services are connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had restarted the excel services in the server after business hours. As this is the production environment and everything working perfectly now. 
The below blog has helped me in figuring out

[workbook cannot be opened](http://www.westportpoint.org/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=37)